# Fiddler: Response Body Was Dropped to Conserve Memory

Tags: fiddler

I'm trying to use Fiddler to capture the response bodies of several video files; one of them is 2.5 GB in size. This one consistently fails to be captured, as it seems that Fiddler has a limit of 2,147.48 MB. I've got 12 GB of RAM and not enough running that I'd top out. Is there any way to disable this function?

Comment: Most likely fiddler stores the data in some array based buffer and arrays are limited to 2GB. Have you tried to enable the streaming mode?

Comment: Yes, this happens even when the streaming button is active. Do you think there might be a way to immediately begin writing these kinds of activities to disk once they begin?

Comment: How should I know. That is something only Telerik can answer you - ask then they have developed Fiddler.

Comment: There are many conceivable ways in which someone on Stack Exchange might know a solution. I have an open thread on the Fiddler forums as well, but it hasn't gotten any response, so I'm asking around in several places that make sense to me to ask. Thanks for your responses so far.